# need Idea for app in WPF

Tags: wpf, silverlight

I've finnished to read all the topics of WPF and I want to develop an application so I'll be sure I got it.

I want it to include all the topics : binding, converters, UCs , MVVM , templates .. etc.

any ideas ?

Answer (score 1):

Huh. Do you have expertize in some area besides programming? Or at least some knowledge?

For additional inspiration, here's [list of ideas YCombinator would fund](http://ycombinator.com/ideas.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can easily start Open source model development. Who knows if you understand WPF better you can even create a new framework altogether which will help the WPF community.

If you want to build an application, might be you can go for something like Video Albums etc, which have large capabilities of rich UI elements.